# Como é que posso fazer um reload a um programa C em caso de ter colocado um valor errado ou quiser correr o programa varias vezes

Tags: c

Estou a fazer um programa em c que calcula a raiz de uma função mas as vezes engano me nos valores (ex. 33.3333 em vez de 3.333333) e não quero correr o programa com os valores errados ou sair e voltar a entrar, logo fazer um restart ou reload do programa seria a solução, também seria uma maneira de correr o programa varias vezes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float main()
{
     char let = 'a';
     int b;
     float x0, erro, gx, x1,dif, gxlinha, absgxlinha;
     int it,val,i, exp, numero, e;
     it=0;
     int num = 0;

     printf("Valor de x0 = ");
     scanf("%f", &x0);

     printf("Valor do erro = ");
     scanf("%f", &erro);

     printf("Qual o valor do expoente maior =  ");
     scanf("%d", &exp);
     printf("\n");
     val = (exp + 1);

     printf("funcao do tipo:  \n\n    ");

     e = exp - 1;
     numero = exp;

     for(b=0;b<=e;b++)
     {
          printf("%cx^%d + ",let,numero);
          let++;
          numero--;
     }

     printf("%cx^%d",let,numero);
     printf("\n\n");

     float a[val];
     printf("Introduza os %d numeros da funcao, de acordo com os valores pedidos: \n",val); // ex.: ax^2 + bx^1 + cx^0 itroduzir pela ordem c, b, a
     printf("\n");

     for( i=0; i<val; i++ )
     {
          printf ("%c = ",let);
          let--;
          scanf("%f", &a[i] );
          gx = gx + (a[i])*(pow((x0),num));
          num++;
     }
     num = 1;

     for (i=1; i<val; i++)
     {
          gxlinha = gxlinha + ((a[i]*num)*(pow((x0),num)));
          num ++;
     }

     absgxlinha = (sqrt(pow(gxlinha,2)));

     if ( absgxlinha < 1)
     {
          printf ("\ng(x0)' < 1 logo a funcao tem pelo menos uma raiz\n");
          x1=gx;
          dif = (sqrt(pow((x1-x0),2)));
          printf("\n| Iter.| Val de x0| g(x0)=x1 |   x1-x0  |\n|      |          |          |          |\n|  %d   | %f | %f | %f |  ",it,x0,x1,dif);

          while (sqrt(pow((x1-x0),2))>=erro)
          {
               x0 = x1;
               gx = 0;
               num = 0;

               for( i=0; i<val; i++ )
               {
                    gx = gx + (a[i])*(pow((x0),num));
                    num++;
               }

               x1=gx;
               dif = (sqrt(pow((x1-x0),2)));
               it++;
               printf(">= %f\n|  %d   | %f | %f | %f |  ",erro,it,x0,x1,dif);
          }
     
          printf("<  %f \n\n",erro);
          printf("A raiz com erro inferior a %f = %f",erro,x1);
          printf("\n\n\n\n");
     }
     else
     {
          printf ("\ng(x0)' > 1 logo a funcao nao tem raizes\n");
     }
}
```

aqui estão uns inputs por ordem

> ```
> 0.8 , 0.000005 , 3 , 0.333333 , 0 , 0 , -0.333333
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**Reload de uma única leitura**

Basta deixar a parte do código que você quer fazer o "reload" dentro de um comando de repetição, isto é, um loop. Exemplo:

```
do
{
    printf("Valor de x0 = ");
    scanf("%f", &x0);

    printf("x0: %f, digite 0 para confirmar", x0);
    scanf("%d", &confirmar);
}while(confirmar != 0);
```

Esse comando vai ler um valor para `x0`, em seguida vai mostrar o conteúdo, de `x0`, e perguntar se realmente era esse número que você queria. Depois de ler sua confirmação (`0` para confirmar ou outro número para refazer a leitura), a condição `confirmar != 0` será avaliada e se for verdade, confirmar for diferente de zero, então o programa vai para o inicio do loop, isto é, ler novamente o valor de `x0`.

Você pode fazer a leitura de mais de uma variável e só depois perguntar:

```
do
{
    printf("Valor de x0 = ");
    scanf("%f", &x0);

    printf("Valor do erro = ");
    scanf("%f", &erro);

    printf("Qual o valor do expoente maior =  ");
    scanf("%d", &exp);

    // Print dos valores

    scanf("%d", &confirmar);
}while(confirmar != 0);
```

**Reload do programa**

Para fazer o "reload" do programa inteiro basta colocar todos os comandos dentro de um loop.

```
// Exemplo de um programa que calcula a idade de uma pessoa
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ano, confirmar;

    do
    {
        printf("Ano de nascimento: ");
        scanf("%d", &ano);

        printf("Idade: %d\n", (2021 - ano));

        printf("Digite 1 para saber a idade de outra pessoa: ");
        scanf("%d", &confirmar);
    }while(confirmar == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Usando a mesma lógica podemos fazer isso no seu programa, ficaria algo assim:

```
do
{
    // Leitura das variaveis

    // Calculos

    // Print dos resultados

    // Etc...

    printf("Digite 1 para calcular a raiz de outra funcao: ");
    scanf("%d", &confirmar);
}while(confirmar == 1);
```